# What does 她是笨蛋的学生 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, conversation

I and my Chinese friend are discussing about the meaning of "她是笨蛋的学生”
So, can u guys tell me which meaning is correct, or which meaning is popularly used: "She is a fool student", or "She is the student of a fool". I mean, the "笨蛋” refers to the teacher or the student?!
Thank you for concerning.

Comment: As 笨蛋的 is not a valid adjective, "She is the student of a fool" would be the only grammatical way to interpret the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

If the sentence is `她是笨蛋学生` or `她是笨学生`, it would mean `She is a fool student`, but since there is a `的` in between, `笨蛋` is a noun that refers to a person, and not an adjective anymore. So `She is the student of a fool` makes better sense.

Comment: Feels more likely that the writer made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am native Chinese. I have to say that in practice such saying is very unlikely to be used. This is swearing at someone.

For a Chinese language learner, it is not the path to go to dig into such things.

Chinese language is not like western languages in that it is very simple in grammar. There is no time tense for verbs. There is no part of speech changes for pronouns etc.

Therefore, do not dig into grammar. Grammar is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0):

的 is of, so 笨蛋 is refers to teacher

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely this was intended to have an adjectival meaning: "she is one dummy of a student." It is a VERY casual way of talking, much more likely to be sent as a text message or post than spoken, but I have seen LOTS of this kind of thing online. Think of it as a Chinese correlate to the pidgin English so many people use when they are posting carelessly.  Don't use it in your assignments, your teacher might have a conniption fit.